# yaml: How to set indentation width?

Tags: indentation

I'm new to editing yaml with emacs.
I currently use `yaml-mode` 20210808.1122 installed like so :

```
(use-package yaml-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.yml\\'" . yaml-mode))
```

I would like to configure how many spaces `TAB` indents because I work in a codebase that uses 4 spaces, and package default seems to be 2 spaces.

How can I do it? If not possible, are there other yaml editing options available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Customize `yaml-indent-offset`. Its doc says:

```
yaml-indent-offset is a variable defined in ‘yaml-mode.el’.
Its value is 2

  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate ‘natnump’.
  You can customize this variable.

Documentation:
*Amount of offset per level of indentation.
```

BTW, I didn't know about this variable before I saw your question, but I found it using some simple methods which you may find useful in the future when you are in a similar situation. The methods involve the awesome help system that emacs provides. If you don't know about it already, then type `C-h ?` and start exploring. Any effort you make to learn how to use the help system will repay you with a huge dividend in the future.

The first component is that emacs packages use a prefix to distinguish the names that the package uses (variables and functions mainly) from those of other packages. For `yaml-mode` as you would expect, the prefix is `yaml-`. The help system allows you to start looking for something, using the prefix, and then ask for `completions`: all the things that emacs knows about that start with that prefix. There are two main roads: if it is a variable (which clearly would be the case here), then the help invocation you want is `C-h v yaml-TAB`. The other road is for functions: `C-h f yaml-TAB`.

`C-h v yaml-TAB` gave me a completion buffer with two dozen entries: giving them the once over, I saw the above variable and clicked on it.

This is a particularly simple case, but I use this method (and its sibling for functions: `C-h f <some prefix>TAB`) all the time.
You can also get at the manuals for emacs itself, and many of its larger packages, using the Info system which you can get to with `C-h i`.

Happy exploring!